# How do App bundles effect app update size

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I have an android app that is 6MB and would like to move to app bundles for adding a third party SDK as optional functionality which is 25MB. If I build the third party SDK in an app bundle I understand app download size on install will be 6MB. Once a user uses the optional feature app bundle will also be downloaded.

My question is after user has downloaded app bundle and I send and update to the main Apk that was originally 6MB, with user already having the app bundle installed will see app update size as 6MB or 31MB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just clarify the vocabulary first. The **App Bundle** is what you upload to the Play Console and will contain two modules: the **base module** (installed during the initial installation - 6 MB in your case) and one **feature module** (installed on-demand - 25 MB in your case).

When an update is available for your app, the Play Store updates all the modules that are already installed. So if one of your user has both the base module and the feature module, then Play will update both.

However, note that Play optimizes what it sends down to users (at least when you push the app in the production track) and will only send patches of what differs in most cases, so unless both the base and feature are completely different from one version to the other, it is unlikely that your users will receive 31 MB of data for the update. This is especially true if your feature module contains a third-party SDK that you don't update often: the size of the update for the feature module will be very small.

I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: I have an app with video assets (so they are available offline). I want to add a new one which is very requested by users. However I am not certain how it would increase the app size. It's compressed, but, is there a way to confirm the impact?